Rank of adjacency matrix of a graph on a sphere all of whose faces have four vertices
Let $G$ be a graph drawn on the sphere such that every face of $G$ has exactly four vertices. Question: can anything be said about the rank of the adjacency matrix of $G$ in terms of other (preferably simple) combinatorial properties of $G$?

A connected graph?

@GerryMyerson Yes, the graph is connected

I would suspect that the more symmetries $G$ has, the higher the nullity of its adjacency matrix, but I have no evidence to back up my suspicion. E.g., the cycle of length four has many symmetries, and its rank is just two. Have you computed any examples, seen any patterns?

Something can be said: it is even:)

I doubt there is much that can be done beyond what follows from the
bipartite nature of these graphs or difficult enumeration of Sachs
subgraphs. The number of
zero eigenvalues will depend on the number of zero coefficients in the low
degree terms of the characteristic polynomial, which are related to the
Sachs subgraphs (elementary subgraphs in Bigg's notation, Ref
1). Two simple examples illustrate
that this is unlikely to have an easy solution.
For the cube graph we have full rank ( = number of vertices = 8). The
characteristic polynomial is
$$
x^{8}-12x^{6}+30x^{4}-28x^{2}+9
$$
with the non-zero constant term 9 accounting for the full rank. (The missing
odd degree terms are because the graph is bipartite.) The Sachs subgraphs
(disjoint cycles and edges covering all 8 vertices) accounting for the value
of the determinant (9) are:

Six graphs (2 per pair of opposite faces) with one 8-cycle. rank = 8 -7
(vertices - components), so sign $=(-1)^{rank}=-1.$ corank = # cycles = 1,
each graph contributes $2^{corank}=2$ permutations; total $=-6\cdot
2^{1}=-12$.

Three graphs (1 per pair of opposite faces) with two squares on opposite
faces; rank $=8-2$; corank $=2$; contribution $+3\cdot 2^{2}=+12$.

Twelve graphs (one per edge) with a 6-cycle around two adjacent faces 
and a disjoint edge; rank $=8-2$; corank $=1$; contribution $
+12\cdot 2^{1}=+24$.

Twelve graphs (two per face) with a square on one face and two parallel
edges on the opposite face (in two possible orientations); rank $=8-3;$
corank $=1$; contribution $+12\cdot 2^{1}=24$.

Nine graphs with 4 disjoint edges; rank $=8-4$; corank $=0$; There are 3
ways to have all 4 edges parallel; another 6 ways to have 2 parallel edges
on one face and 2 parallel edges on the opposite face, but not parallel to
the first pair; contribution $=+9\cdot 2^{0}=9$.


The first four possibilities cancel out and only the last survives. The
cancellation seems fortuitous and the fact that the total is non-zero is not
readily predictable without enumeration. The enumerations depend on the
symmetry, and could probably be counted with Polya counting. but there is no
obvious pattern.
Consider now a graph with 11 vertices, 9 faces and $D_{3h}$ point group
symmetry (J??ErYsw?w? in graph6 encoding). The characteristic polynomial is
$$
x^{11}-18x^{9}+93x^{7}-188x^{5}+132x^{3}
$$
This time the rank is 8, with 3 zero eigenvalues. One of these arises
automatically from the bipartite nature - the eigenvalues come in $\pm
\lambda $ pairs, and since there are an odd number of vertices, the unpaired
eigenvalue must be zero. In terms of Sachs subgraphs, all cycles are even
and the disjoint edges must leave an isolated vertex, so there are no valid
Sachs subgraphs. For the coefficient of $x^{1}$, there are 7 types of Sachs
subgraphs contributing $-72-72-96-192+180+96+156=0$. Again this seems
fortuitous. Now that this coefficient is zero the next coefficient of $x^{2}$
is zero because of the bipartite nature/lack of odd-length cycles.
Aside from the fact that for an odd number of vertices the rank must be at
least one less than full rank, I don't see any simple pattern here. The
symmetry enters into this, but the symmetries can be very different for
graphs of comparable numbers of vertices or faces.

N. Biggs, Algebraic Graph Theory, Ch 7, 2nd Ed, Cambridge University
Press, 1974.

Update
After the comments about odd vertices, etc, by the others, I took another look
at the adjacency matrix for the second example above, which has graph

The adjacency matrix in standard bipartite block form is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The nonzero blocks are transposes of each other and each have rank 4 (of
course must be the same), giving total rank 8. The rows of the top right
block all have three 1s, reflecting that all the vertices in the first
partition have degree three. Since the block is $6\times 5$ it must be less
than full rank;, because the partitions here are of different sizes. The
bottom left block has mixed degrees. Notice that there are two rows in the
bottom left block that have three 1s, but if we consider all 8 rows for
degree 3 vertices, they have less than rank 8, so the situation with
counting odd vertices is not immediately evident. There probably is more
that could be said in such an analysis, but it would seem to relate to
bipartite graphs with specific degree sequences, and not much to faces with
4 vertices or the embedding on the sphere.

Well, in the latest example there are eight rows of odd sum, so eight odd vertices and tye rank is eight, so there's that.

This is not exactly an answer, but too long for a comment.
In general, the rank is not a very useful graph parameter, mostly you expect graphs to have full rank unless they cannot.
However it doesn't hurt to look at some data and see if anything interesting stands out.
Using plantri to generate quadrangulations and then counting up the ranks, we get
12 vertices:
(10, 1)
(12, 2)

(This means rank 10 occurred once and rank 12 occurred twice)
13 vertices:
(10, 1)
(12, 2)

14 vertices:
(8, 1)
(10, 1)
(12, 3)
(14, 6)

15 vertices:
(12, 4)
(14, 14)

16 vertices:
(12, 2)
(14, 26)
(16, 30)

17 vertices:
(12, 3)
(14, 28)
(16, 108)

18 vertices:
(12, 1)
(14, 16)
(16, 208)
(18, 226)

19 vertices:
(14, 7)
(16, 198)
(18, 1121)

20 vertices:
(12, 1)
(14, 10)
(16, 149)
(18, 2278)
(20, 2023)

21 vertices:
(16, 60)
(18, 2347)
(20, 12147)

Sometimes the extremal values (of anything) belong to highly structured graphs, so we might look at the 20-vertex graph of rank 12 and see if it has a nice structure.
If we take the dual graph (which is a 4-regular graph) and plot it nicely then we get a pretty picture, but that's about all.


I see slightly more than just thatbpretty picture. The dual graph has 12 odd-sided faces, so G will have 12 odd vertices, whose count matches the computed rank. I have made a conjecture in my updated answer that the odd vertices will count the rank.
